# Fix a CSS conflict

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add a pricing table on default landing page of my wordpress site. But because of the following stylesheet code (which is required by the current theme and can't be changed) the pricing table doesn't appear properly.

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You can have a look on pricing table here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Ppr2K/

Can you guyz please help me to fix it ?

Comment: give a special class for your price table and you could modify your style less conflit.

Answer (score 1):

Make the below change to solve your issue.

```
div.p_table_1 div.caption_column li.header_row_2 {
    height: 100px;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ppr2K/1/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are so fast Nathan :p

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast but it didn't solve the issue properly. This is how i want the table to appear: http://jsfiddle.net/Ppr2K/2/

Comment: So http://jsfiddle.net/Ppr2K/2/ what you provided above is the solution? If yes, then what is the question? - @Alex

Comment: If you can check again the following code is missing on the solution page. 

*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

I want the table to appear properly with that code.

Comment: Then I suggest you to make the below changes to your code and check. `*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}` - @Alex Do let me know if it is still affecting other pages or not. Also, do the above change if it is still affecting other pages. `*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}`

Comment: oh.. Then what you can do is create an internal style sheet specifically on this page where you are getting the issue and apply the below style sheet and your problem will be resolved. `*, *:before, *:after { -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; -moz-box-sizing: content-box; box-sizing: content-box; }`. Add `!important` if it does not work. - @Alex

Comment: It didn't work. The other pages on my site are still getting affected.

Comment: It will not. If you use internal styling, it will only affect to the page where you want it to work. - @Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this one

```
div.p_table_1 div.caption_column li.header_row_2 {
    height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0px 6px 10px !important;
```

}

Comment: Sorry, It didn't work. Pricing table doesn't appear properly.